# Contacts never synced to Pardot

Tags: pardot, sync

I am coming into a system where I am in charge of migrating the mktg automation platform from Pardot to Hubspot.

I've found that there are about 1500 contacts that were created in salesforce that never synced to pardot (they have empty pardot created date). There were only ~40 leads that never synced to pardot as well.

They were created gradually over the course of the last couple years, so there wasn't like one large import or anything.

Does anyone have an idea of why these contacts aren't syncing to pardot? Is it that pardot does not accept anything that isn't a lead or converted lead? For example, if the sales reps are creating contacts in salesforce will pardot not accept those into it's database?

Thanks in advance,

M

Here are our connector settings: 
[image]

Comment: Do these unsynced leads and contacts contain email addresses?

Answer (score 2):

- no email address
- they were created before pardot was implemented with Salesforce, so they would need to be manually uploaded into pardot.
- Pardot will only be able to read leads/contacts that the connector user is available to see under the Salesforce sharing rules.